# Resolving promises in service dependency

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rest, angularjs

I develop client side with AngularJS for Rails application and I stuck with authenticity_token.

Here is how my service looks like:

```
blog_app.factory('AuthenticityToken', ['$http', '$q',
  ($http, $q) ->
    () ->
      delay = $q.defer()
      $http.get('/authenticity_token').success(
        (data) ->
          delay.resolve(data.authenticity_token)
      ).error(
        ->
          delay.reject('Can\'t get authenticity_token')
      )

      return delay.promise
])


post_services.factory('Post', ['$resource',
  ($resource) ->
    $resource('/posts/:id', {id: '@id'},
    {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {limit: 10, order: 'desk'},
        isArray: false
      }
    }
    )
])
```

How can I make *AuthenticityToken* be injected and resolved in *Post*, so I could use authenticity token in *Post*'s default params?

Instead I can only resolve it for controller:

```
angular.module('posts', ['posts.services']).config(
  ['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
    $routeProvider
    .when('/posts', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/posts/',
        controller: 'ListCtrl',
        resolve: {
          authenticity_token: ['AuthenticityToken', (AuthenticityToken) ->
            AuthenticityToken()
          ]
        }
    })
  ]
)
```

And then pass to *Post* resource explicitly

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('posts', ['posts.services']).config(
  ['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) ->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = token
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['X-CSRF-Token'] = token
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = token

    $routeProvider
    .when('/posts', {
        templateUrl: '/pages/posts/',
        controller: 'ListCtrl'
    })
  ]
)
```

Comment: I ask you about promise resolution, in place of AuthenticityToken service may be another one, and I need to resolve promise before injection